# apt-get Update still tries to download from tor project after uninstalling tor

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall, package-management, tor

I installed Tor using the directions here and now I want to uninstall it:
https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian

I wanted to uninstall tor and remove all configuration files so I ran the following in terminal:
sudo apt-get purge tor

I then went to the /etc/apt/sources.list file and removed the reference to

> deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org  main

My problem is that I still get the following messages when running "sudo apt-get update" in terminal:

```
Ign http://deb.torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION> Release.gpg
Ign http://deb.torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION> Release
Ign http://deb.torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION>/main TranslationIndex
Err http://deb.torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION>/main amd64 Packages   404 Not Found [IP: 93.95.227.222 80]
Err http://deb.torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION>/main i386 Packages   404  Not Found [IP: 93.95.227.222:80]
Ign http://deb.torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION>/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://deb.torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION>/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/<DISTRIBUTION>/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 93.95.227.222 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/<DISTRIBUTION>/main/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found [IP: 93.95.227.222 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I want Tor completely removed, so when I ask Ubuntu to update it won't talk to the Tor project at all. As you can tell I am a beginner. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have effectively uninstalled Tor but haven't removed the repositories. Depending how you added them one of these solutions should work:

```
sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*tor*.list
```

or

```
sudo sed -i '/torproject/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i '/torproject/d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Now you can do `sudo apt-get update`. If it doesn't work add the output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Answer (score 1):

Check for entries containing references to the TOR repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, remove those and do an `apt-get update` afterwards.